# Connect JProgressBar with download process

Tags: java, swing, download, jprogressbar

I have the below code. I can't make it work.

I have to mention that the URL is redirecting. I mean that `url = http://www.thissite.com` and redirects to `http://www.othersite.com`. But I want to get it work with the initial `url`.

```
 public void download(String address, String localFileName, JProgressBar progress ) {
    OutputStream out = null;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try {

          URL url = new URL(address);



        // Open an output stream to the destination file on our local filesystem
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/MusicDownloads/"+localFileName));
        conn = url.openConnection();

        in = conn.getInputStream();

        int length = conn.getContentLength(); //find out how long the file is, any good webserver should provide this info
         int current = 0;
          progress.setMaximum(length); //we're going to get this many bytes
          progress.setValue(0); //we've gotten 0 bytes so far

        // Get the data
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numRead = 0;

        while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            current=0;
            out.write(buffer, current, numRead);

              current += numRead; //we've progressed a little so update current

            progress.setValue(current); //tell progress how far we are


        }
        // Done! Just clean up and get out
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Shouldn't happen, maybe add some logging here if you are not
            // fooling around ;)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to fix your re-directing problem, but what about the JProgressBar isn't working? Are you making sure to call this code off of the EDT? You will need to make sure that you call the JProgressBar's `setValue(...)` method ***on*** the EDT.

Comment: i am calling download("http://www.site.com", "file.txt", jProgressBar1)l to start the download and the progressbar stays stucked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) instead.

Comment: Don't forgot to take a look at the tutorial for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java give a good simple example of how to use the SwingWorker to run ProgressBar in an other thread.

Comment: i checked it.....where must i add my download code? inside the doinbackground? or elsewhere ?

Comment: @JessyJameson: definitely do it in a background thread which a SwingWorker's `doInBackground` provides for you.